# Working out ICopy from a current mirror [Mosfet]

Tags: mosfet, current-mirror

I'm trying to solve for \$I_{copy}\$, but I've looked around on the internet and cannot find an explanation. However, I know the formula:

\$ I_{copy} =\frac{I_{REF} * W_1/L_1}{W_{REF}/L_{REF}}\$

but don't understand how to work this out from the circuit diagram.

Attached is an image explanation my problem. Answer for:

- The circuit on the left: \$I_{copy}=\frac{2}{8I_{REF}}\$
- The circuit on the right:  \$I_{copy}= 7I_{REF}\$

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is for **one** current mirror. You could use it to determine the current through the NMOS marked 2(W/L)n in the left circuit.

That current would then be 2/3 * Iref.

That same current is fed into a **2nd** current mirror, the one with 2 PMOS transistors. Use the same formula again but note what the input current is: 2/3 Iref

The right schematic is slightly more complex but using the formula you can determine the currents through the NMOS marked 5(W/L)n and 3(W/L)n.

Then again solve the currents in the PMOS mirror.

At the output what happens to those 2 currents? Use the current law if you must.